# Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax in Lumen 5.6

Tags: mysql, mongodb, lumen

in my lumen 5.6 i have mysql as my default db connection and mongodb. everything is great until i tried to execute 2 DB in one query.

on my controller

```
public function try(){        

    $userinfo = DB::connection('mongodb')->table('userinformations')
                    ->get();
    print_r($userinfo);
    $user = DB::table('users')
            ->join($userinfo, 'users.iduser', '=', 'userinformations.iduser')
            ->select('users.iduser','users.nickname')
            ->get();

    return response()->json($user);
}
```

on QueryCallback log
'select `users`.`iduser`, `users`.`nickname` from `users` inner join `[{"_id":{"$oid":"5b46df3ee781b6ff1b1e0096"},

but when i print_r the collection

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection Object
```

(
    [items:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [_id] => MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId Object
                        (
                            [oid] => 5b46df3ee781b6ff1b1e0096
                        )

```
                [iduser] => 1
                [gender] => Male
                [profilephoto] => assets/profile/12.png
                [birth] => 2000-25-12
                [city] => Quezon City
                [mStatus] => Married
            )
```

thanks in advance